# static angular select option

Tags: html, angular

```
<input  [formControl]="twitterHandle" id="twitterHandle" placeholder="twitterHandle">
```

in there i get input via that and using following code get the input value

```
twitterHandle=new FormControl();
twitterHandle:this.twitterHandle.value,
```

simillar way i need to add static select input to form how to do that and how to edit following

```
<select>
   <option value="option">country1</option>
      <option value="option1">Sri lanka</option>
      <option value="option2">Canada</option>
</select>
```

Comment: you can use another ``formControl`` and bind it to the select element

Comment: when i do that that first option in there don't show  in page

Comment: that is because the ``formControl`` has initial value as empty .so set it to ``option`` and then you are good to go

Comment: how to set that

Comment: can you post how your form is defined ?

Comment: when page loding in first time i need to show some message or some thing on that select how to do that

Answer (score 0):

You just have to define another formControl :

```
selectControl : FormControl = new FormControl();
```

and you can initialize the control :

```
  ngOnInit(){
    this.selectControl.setValue('option')
  }
```

In your template ,

```
<form>
  <select [formControl]='selectControl' (change)='test()'>
  <option [value]='"option"'>Option1</option>
  <option [value]='"option1"'>Option2</option>
</select>
</form>
```

you can check the value changes in the `test()` as defined below :

```
  test(){
  console.log(this.selectControl.value);
  }
```

You can See the example : https://angular-wytvwr.stackblitz.io

Hope this helps